# Assertion failed in file, memcpy argument ranges overlap: MPI_Scatter

Tags: c, mpi

Below is my code. Currently, it is trying to distribute work to be done for a 1d representation of a matrix (2d array). I MPI_Scatter the portion of the array which needs work. I store that portion into local_C which should be of the same size as the portion sent. I also broadcast the M (col), Q (used for gather function as col size), ....

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank;
    int nproc;
    int n_local;
    int N; // rows
    int M; // rows/columns
    int Q; // columns

    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv); /* intialize MPI*/
    MPI_Comm comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &nproc);
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);

   int *matrixA;
   int *matrixB;
   int *matrixC;
   int *local_C;

   // manager core constructs factors of matrix representation
   if (rank == 0) {

     N = atoi(argv[1]);
     M = atoi(argv[2]);
     Q = atoi(argv[3]);

     // check if correct number of input
     if (argc != 4) {
       printf("Enter <filename> <N> <M> <Q>\n");
       exit(1);
     }
     else if (N % nproc != 0) { // check if N is a multiple of the number of processors
       printf("Ensure N is divisible by number of processors: %i\n", nproc);
       exit(1);
     }

     // create matrices of size
     matrixA = malloc(N * M * sizeof(long));
     randomlyFillArray(matrixA, N * M);
     matrixB = malloc(M * Q * sizeof(long));
     randomlyFillArray(matrixB, M * Q);

     // create resulting product matrix of size
     matrixC = malloc(N * Q * sizeof(long));

     // sequential compute
     //computeMatrixProductSequentially(matrixA, matrixB, matrixC, M, N, Q);

     // parallel compute

     // block data
     n_local = N / nproc;
     local_C = malloc(n_local * M * sizeof(long));

     MPI_Bcast(&M, 1, MPI_INT, 0, comm);
     MPI_Bcast(&Q, 1, MPI_INT, 0, comm);
     MPI_Bcast(&n_local, 1, MPI_INT, 0, comm);

     // scatter matrixA for n_local row to cores
     MPI_Scatter(&matrixA, n_local * M, MPI_LONG, &local_C, n_local * M, MPI_LONG, 0, comm);

     // broadcast matrixB to all cores
     MPI_Bcast(&matrixB, 1, MPI_LONG, 0, comm);

     }
   }
   else {
     MPI_Bcast(&M, 1, MPI_INT, 0, comm);
     MPI_Bcast(&Q, 1, MPI_INT, 0, comm);
     MPI_Bcast(&n_local, 1, MPI_INT, 0, comm);

     // scatter recv matrixA row
     MPI_Scatter(&matrixA, n_local * M, MPI_LONG, &local_C, n_local * M, MPI_LONG, 0, comm);

     // broadcast recv matrixB
     MPI_Bcast(&matrixB, 1, MPI_LONG, 0, comm);

     //MPI_Gather();

   }

   MPI_Finalize();

   return 0;
 }
```

Here is the error when trying to compile and run the program.
[image: Error]

The purpose, in case it matters, is to multiply two matrices in parallel using 1d arrays.

Comment: Please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Always copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: `memcpy` is not defined to copy overlapping ranges.  If you meant to copy overlapping ranges, use `memmove`.  If you didn't mean to copy overlapping ranges, you must have a bug in your scatter/gather logic.

Comment: Also, `int *matrixC;` and `matrixC = malloc(N * Q * sizeof(long));` Is the `sizeof` correct here? It won't cause any trouble, but could waste memory.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the size of the matrices. @SteveSummit I'm not sure what memcpy even is. All I am meaning to do is to scatter the rows to the cores in which I provide a pointer, like you are supposed to do.

Comment: @SteveSummit Honestly the error sounds like a malloc issue to me. If the memory ranges overlap, I don't see how that is something I can control considering I am using malloc to allocate memory for the arrays.

Comment: @Displayname Apologies, I didn't notice that the `memcpy` call was not in your code.

Comment: Are we sure that `MPI_Scatter(&matrixA, ...)` is correct? This is taking the *address* of the buffer rather than the *value* of the buffer, and it doesn't feel right. Likewise with `matrixB` and `local_C`. Try removing `&`.

Comment: This is worth running under a debugger: compile with `-g -ggdb` and then run `gdb` to find the stack backtrace, which will show you which of your own calls is doing this.

Comment: Also, I don't know MPI at all, but if rank is nonzero, then `MPI_Scatter` is operating with uninitialized variables (this is the "else" branch of the main if).

Comment: @SteveSummit In an MPI code this "overlap" message typically comes from incorrect buffer specifications, so that the send & receive operations touch the same memory. If you have only a single machine, MPI uses memcpy for the send operation.

Comment: @SteveFriedl Well spotted. the OP seems to assume that the Scatter call on receiving processes will create the matrix, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that MPI calls take a `int*` or `double*` or `whateversimpletype*` argument. Your `MatrixA` is `int*`, so using `&MatrixA` makes the buffer `int**`. Solution: pass `MatrixA` directly as buffer.

Also: you are coding as if the scatter operation on non-zero ranks creates the matrix. That is not the case. You need to allocate the array yourself, and MPI will write the values into it.

Another remark: scattering a matrix is not a scalable solution and is bad MPI coding. It introduces both a memory bottleneck, because your process zero needs to be able to store *all* the data, and a time bottleneck because all otehr processes have to wait for process zero to construct the matrix. The right way to code this is to let each process construct its own part of the matrix. Always keep your data structure distributed from start to end!